# Win10 - can't reach ubuntu VM after last big windows update (again :-/ )

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, vpn, vagrant

Once again after major windows update my virtualbox networking went down the drain...

My VMs are starting and I can connect to them via vagrant port forwarding. But I cannot reach them from windows host on the internal network (pinging them on 10.0.0.30). VMs have connection to the outside world. Also VMs (I have two with the same vagrant file, differs only in last IP segment) can ping themselves on static IPs in this private network.

I suspect it is either windows firewall or incorrect routing on host. But I cannot find a way to make it work again.

Details:

Host: Windows 10 Pro with VirtualBox
Guest: Ubuntu (box: ubuntu/xenial64)

Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-

# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", mount_options: ["dmode=777,fmode=666"]
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 8192
 v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end

  config.vm.define :dev do |dev|
    dev.vm.hostname = "local-dev" 
    dev.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.30"
    dev.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
    dev.vm.provision :shell,
      inline: 'PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ansible-playbook \
        /vagrant/ansible/dev.yml -c local'


  end

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
    config.cache.scope = :box
  end

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest")
    config.vbguest.auto_update = false
    config.vbguest.no_install = true
    config.vbguest.no_remote = true
  end


end
```

ifconfig on guest ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@local-dev:~$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:0b:f0:0e:b8
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:bff:fef0:eb8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:11583 (11.5 KB)


enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:6e:aa:4e:78:a9
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e:aaff:fe4e:78a9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:97907 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:85101631 (85.1 MB)  TX bytes:2663603 (2.6 MB)


enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d4:43:c2
          inet addr:10.0.0.30  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fed4:43c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:24608 (24.6 KB)  TX bytes:17882 (17.8 KB)


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:2520 (2.5 KB)  TX bytes:2520 (2.5 KB)


veth6b6e39b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7e:a7:58:89:5a:f4
          inet6 addr: fe80::7ca7:58ff:fe89:5af4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:12231 (12.2 KB)
```

ipconfig on windows host:

```
> ipconfig /all


Windows IP Configuration


   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : antigro_ciesiel
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0E-C6-E3-26-C3
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek USB GbE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-E0-4C-02-09-27
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes


Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #5:


   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-04
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2457:af67:45f4:7d18%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 67764263
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-A9-43-A1-00-0E-C6-E3-26-C3
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled


Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #6:


   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #6
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-2F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d466:173f:3d9f:8a4e%47(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 789184551
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-A9-43-A1-00-0E-C6-E3-26-C3
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 10-02-B5-CD-F4-20
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 12-02-B5-CD-F4-1F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-EE-9A-6B-4A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes


Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:


   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 10-02-B5-CD-F4-1F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::14f:78ac:ef5:ee8b%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.21.181(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : wtorek, 12 czerwca 2018 09:20:56
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : wtorek, 12 czerwca 2018 14:01:18
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.21.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.21.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 772801205
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-22-A9-43-A1-00-0E-C6-E3-26-C3
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.21.1
                                       8.8.8.8
                                       188.117.188.117
                                       89.25.182.14
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Route table on windows host:

```
> route PRINT
===========================================================================
Interface List
 28...00 0e c6 e3 26 c3 ......ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
 24...00 e0 4c 02 09 27 ......Realtek USB GbE Family Controller
  4...0a 00 27 00 00 04 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #5
 47...0a 00 27 00 00 2f ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #6
 31...10 02 b5 cd f4 20 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 14...12 02 b5 cd f4 1f ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 33...00 ff ee 9a 6b 4a ......TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
 13...10 02 b5 cd f4 1f ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================


IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.10.21.1     10.10.21.181     45
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
         10.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
       10.10.21.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.10.21.181    301
     10.10.21.181  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.10.21.181    301
     10.10.21.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.10.21.181    301
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.10.21.181    301
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.10.21.181    301
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None


IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 47    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  4    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    301 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    301 fe80::14f:78ac:ef5:ee8b/128
                                    On-link
  4    281 fe80::2457:af67:45f4:7d18/128
                                    On-link
 47    281 fe80::d466:173f:3d9f:8a4e/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 47    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
  4    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    301 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I am about to loose last hair over this thing...

I recall that some time ago I was solving something like this by adding missing routing somewhere (guest or host) but can't remember what exactly nor can I find any help online...

**[EDIT] - Resolved**, after 2 days of biting keyboard over it...

The problem was some weird interaction between networking stack, virtualbox adapters and NordVPN/NordVPN TAP Driver. Everything was working fine together before last windows update and went belly up after that.

I have uninstalled NordVPN and related TAP driver, uninstalled network interfaces and let windows reinstall them after restart. Now it is working as expecting. I will now try to reinstall Nord VPN on top of it and see if it still works.

Comment: Ah the wonderful world of the ever evolving Windows 10, that has to suck. I hope you find a solution, if you do, be sure to come back and post it as an answer.

Comment: By now I have removed all virtualbox network adapters, uninstalled and reinstalled virtualbox and started new box with much simplified config. Still no joy. Will update if I find some solution for this

Comment: @Moab resolved this sucker :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was some weird interaction between networking stack, virtualbox adapters and NordVPN/NordVPN TAP Driver. Everything was working fine together before last windows update and went belly up after that.

I have uninstalled NordVPN and related TAP driver, uninstalled network interfaces and let windows reinstall them after restart. Now it is working as expecting. I will now try to reinstall Nord VPN on top of it and see if it still works.