# Windows 10 - General failure when pinging my own IP (works for localhost)

Tags: networking, windows-10, ping

This is related to me trying to resolve problem from this question ([Win10 - can't reach ubuntu VM after last big windows update (again :-/ )](https://superuser.com/questions/1330686/win10-cant-reach-ubuntu-vm-after-last-big-windows-update-again)).

System: windows 10 pro. 
Problem: pinging my own IP returnes general failure:

**`ipconfig`**:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.21.181
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.21.1
```

**`ping 10.10.21.181`**:

```
C:\Users\wojtek>ping 10.10.21.181

Pinging 10.10.21.181 with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.

Ping statistics for 10.10.21.181:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Does anybody has any idea what might be the reason? Or how to proceed in trying to resolve this?

**[EDIT] - Resolved**. The problem was some weird interaction between networking stack, virtualbox adapters and NordVPN/NordVPN TAP Driver. Everything was working fine together before last windows update and went belly up after that.

I have uninstalled NordVPN and related TAP driver, uninstalled network interfaces and let windows reinstall them after restart. Now it is working as expecting. I will now try to reinstall Nord VPN on top of it and see if it still works.

Comment: Please read [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) Then remove your solution from the question, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to uninstall and reinstall NordVPN. There's a setting in the software that when turned on, makes your computer "invisible" to others on the network when connected to the VPN. Even though NordVPN wasn't running, it still had impact. The fix? Turn that setting off and you'll be able to see your network again.

Comment: ... and if that doesn't work then try disabling *nordvpn-service*.